# how to resolve conflict with path on tfs

Tags: c#, tfs

I have Unit test. On csproj file the path write this way:

```
<Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Dependency\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But when I build project on tfs, After compile I see warning:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DocumentFormat.OpenXml". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Because this path (....\Dependency\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll) doesn't exist. The current directory is /bin. So how can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `..\..\Dependency\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` file isn't checked-in to TFS.  Check it in in an appropriate location in the solution and update the reference in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: This file checked-in to TFS. But when project build, the current directory different as current directory when build from visual studio.

Comment: In that case put the dependency in a folder in the solution root, not in the bin folder. TFS has a different output structure than Visual a Studio.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem having added DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll via the Nuget package. Going through the references that the package had created we found that rather than referencing the installed dll, it was instead referencing a copy in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5`.

After initially adding a copy of the DLL to the solution directly and changing the references to get it building on TFS, we tried just manually reinstalling the package from the Package Manager Console using `Update-Package -reinstall DocumentFormat.OpenXml` which recreated the references with the correct path to the copy in the packages folder and the error did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Copy library *.dll to place where is project executable.

Comment: You know. This is library exist on current directory. But throw warning anyway.